# Convert string which retrieve from database in a If condition

Tags: php, database, yii, expression

I have stored some rules/logic in a column in database. With that retried rule I want to make it a condition. Since the retrieved rule is returning as string value my condition  gives me TRUE for always.

let's say

```
$www = $rule->logic; // $rule ->logic = (20 >  3) and (20 <  5)
    if($www ){                          
        $this->logger->debug('commision granted');
            }else{
        $this->logger->debug('commision noooo');
            }
```

However If I simply use `if ((20 >  3) and (20 <  5))` Then I can get a correct answer. 
I have no idea how to convert $www ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP `eval()` to execute expression:

```
$www = $rule->logic; // $rule ->logic = (20 >  3) and (20 <  5)
if(eval("return $www;")){                          
    echo 'commision granted';
        }else{
    echo 'commision noooo';
        }
```